# how to change wordpress english to wordpress arabic?

Tags: wordpress, arabic

the site currently working with Wordpress English. now I want to change it to Wordpress Arabic. the theme , posts everything same. the theme supports RTL. so the contents should so in right to left for that I want to change the English version to Arabic version?

is that possible? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Wordpress version 4.1 you should be able to change language by visiting:

Settings > General : Change Site Language option value.

Language can be selected from a list of available languages.